# Need PayPal PDT Sample Code in Client JavaScript

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm new to PayPal and its PDT. I've searched through many posts but they require **Node.js** or **PHP** to implement it. I don't have both, but I just want a simple return from PayPal PDT, telling my **download.html** that the purchase was successful so that I can safely display the product key to my customers and allow them to download my digital product, otherwise I will do something like this in my JavaScript:

```
If (purchaseFailed) {
   window.location.replace('/404.html');
}
```

The reason that I do that is to prevent direct access to my **download.html** and reveal the product key without making a payment through PayPal.

**I've enabled my PayPal PDT and specified the return URL**, but I just do not know how to write the JavaScript to get the return the status from PayPal. I do not need to display any transaction detail to my customers except a 'thank you' message, the product key, and the download link (but if you can show some sample on getting the transaction details, e.g. product code and customer email address, that would help too). Can somebody help me with some simple JavaScript that my **Google Blogger HTML** can execute it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

PDT is completely unreliable, because returns are never guaranteed to happen, due to browser/network crashes or the customer not waiting for the auto-return (there is a timer) or not clicking through to return (typically guests w/o an account must be shown a receipt and click to return). So PDT is suitable for informational purposes only (e.g. showing buyers a thank you message when they do return.).

Absolutely no business logic such as downloads should depend on a PDT return actually occurring.

Instead, if you need a dependable notification from PayPal of payment completion, an asynchronous IPN or one of the newer webhooks should be listened for -- or alternatively, the integration should be changed to a more robust synchronous server-side one such as this pattern: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , where there is always an immediate API response on payment capture for notification purposes.

Blogger's HTML/JS does not provide any of the necessary listening or API capabilities, of course.

Comment: Hi Preston, thanks for the reply and good advice! I just temporary made use of `document.referrer` just to make sure the `download.html` was actually loaded by PayPal and not others or faked by the hacker by copy-n-paste URL on browser. But yes, that doesn't guarantee the success of the purchase either, that's the problem!